# Unable to get the input field values in streamlit

Tags: session-state, streamlit

I am new to this. Yet I am trying to do something. I have created some input fields like text_area, text_input, and some more. I am not using form for some reason. So I created a button that clears the input values( i am using session state and re-initializing the values with empty). The main problem here is I am unable to store the input values after pressing the button. Tried doing so many ways.

for sample idea:

```py
store_the_inputfields=[]
def some_fun():
   global store_the_inputfields
   def clear_fun():
        st.session_state["inputfields_values"] =""

   input fields --> getting the input from the user and assigning it
   store_the_inputfields.append(list(st.session_state.keys()))--> 
#appending all the user entered values i.e input fields values to store_the_inputfields
   #button (which clears the values by calling on_click =clear_fun)


def view_values():
   st.write(store_the_inputfields)

some_fun()
view_values()
```

please correct me if there is any mistake

Edit:
What I am asking is, for each session state values I want to append them to a list.

Example:

```
store=[]

form 1 values: 
x= examp1
y=examp2
st.session_state["x"] = "examp1"
st.session_state["y"] = "examp2"
store.append(list(st.session_state.items()))
```

this is printing the result, the difficulty starts when we submit another form.

the store contains only that form values not the values of the previous form. I am asking that. how to store the previous form values and append the current form values with previous form values in the list

```
form 2 values:
x= examp3
y=examp4
st.session_state[“x”] = “examp3”
st.session_state[“y”] = “examp4”
store.append(list(st.session_state.items()))
```

now when we print it should give

```
 [[["x","examp1"],["y","examp2"]],[["x","examp3"],["y","examp4"]]]
```

this is what I am asking for.

Comment: Could you add some input widgets that you use instead of `the input fields getting the values from the user` This can be tricky if you have more than 1 input widget and you are not using a form widget. Remember when you change something on the widget, streamlit will rerun the code from top to bottom. From experience, the root cause of many issues in streamlit is because of the core concept of code top to bottom rerun has not been properly understood.

Comment: But the rerun is not removing the values in the input field. and next form. I can't able to do some immediate operations unless the form is submitted so I didn't use that

Comment: Complete your code, add the input widgets first. State what is your problem.

Comment: Hope you will get it now. I added some more in the question

Comment: Sorry but your form code does not make any sense. Study [this](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form) and write a form widget properly.